# Import-Module PowerTab

Tags: powershell

How can I import this module without these warnings:

Import-Module PowerTab

```
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the Internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. Do you want to run C:\Users\someone\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerTab\Handlers\PSClientManager.ps1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"):
```

Comment: what's the result of `get-ExecutionPolicy` in your console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think depends for you executionpolicy configuration:

you can try with

```
set-executionpolicy bypass
```

or

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

or

```
   set-executionpolicy unrestricted
```

or you need to `unblock` the zip file (or all files exctracted from it) of the module before extract file in module folder:

You can just select Properties and under Security click "Unblock." Clicking Unblock completely removes  the `Zone.Identifier Alternative Data Stream` and makes scripts (and other things) executable.

and read helpwith:

```
get-help about_execution_policies -full
```